# Windows 8 always fails to login every restart after I changed the password to my MS account

Tags: windows-8, passwords

So this isn't like the other similar issues. I'm not locked out of my account.

I've changed my MS account password online and restarted my computer. After the restart it obviously didn't auto-login me like usual because the cached password was bad. So I re-enter the password and it works like it should except that now every time I restart I need to do it again. I get a yellow message informing me the password is incorrect, I type in my current password, I get logged on.

I've tried turning on the option to require password on wake up and then doing a restart cycle hoping that that would change the cached password but it didn't. As soon as I turn the option off the same symptoms appear.

Comment: Did you have your system configured to automatically log into the account, if so, disable that configuration then restart.  Once you confirm it no longer attempts to automatically log you in, configure it again, that should solve the problem

Comment: The only option I managed to find is the one where you chose weather a password is required on wakeup. That had no effect. I also tried this: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-automatic-sign-in-after-installing-windows-updates but the setting simply changed nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Try this first:
Like Abdelhafid said, run `control userpasswords2`. Then tick the "Users must enter username and..." checkbox and click OK. Restart PC. Sign in. Open the same menu. Untick the box and hit apply. Hopefully you will be asked to reenter your password that will be used to sign in automatically.

If that didn't work, you can change your password from within windows to some temporary password, and then change it back. Throw in a restart in the middle for good measure. One caveat is that the online form to change the password is a bit more lenient and allows you to set simpler passwords. The one in windows has restrictions like mandatory uppercase and lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to log on with another Administrator account to complete the next steps.

**1-** Press the **Windows + R** keys on the keyboard. you have Run dialog.
**2-** Type `control userpasswords2` and press Enter.it will bring up the classic User Accounts applet.
**3-** In the User Accounts window, find your Microsoft Account.
**4-** Select your Ms Account from the list below
**5-** Click the button reset password.
**6-** Choose your new password and confirm it.

Restart or log off to test the new password.

Comment: I couldn't reset the password from another account even if the other account was also an administrator. I've managed to find the option to do it through some menu digging but it warned be about potentially loosing data. Anyways, I've found a less destructive solution.